# undefined method '+' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

This is my class:

```
class Combatant < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :resource_current

  def change_resource(amount)
    resource_current += amount
    if resource_current < 0
      resource_current = 0
    elsif resource_current > 100
      resource_current = 100
    end
  end
end
```

When executing change_resource on an object of Combatant class I am getting:

```
undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
```

Of course resource_current has been initialized and has a value of 6.

When I change the method to:

```
  def change_resource(amount)
    self.resource_current += amount
    if resource_current > 100
      resource_current = 100
    elsif resource_current < 0
      resource_current = 0
    end
  end
```

It goes:

```
undefined method `<' for nil:NilClass
```

So I add another 'self':

```
  def change_resource(amount)
    self.resource_current += amount
    if resource_current > 100
      resource_current = 100
    elsif self.resource_current < 0
      resource_current = 0
    end
  end
```

The method is working now.
Why? Why I don't need another 'self' for the first condition (if resource_current > 100)?
Why do I need 'self' at all?

Comment: Because without it you may be declaring a local `resource_current` instead of accessing the methods generated by Rails from the DB schema.

Comment: Ok, I suppose that the first line of code `resource_current += amount` could be interpreted as declaration of local variable. But why do I need to use `self` in the second condition? And why I don't need one in the first condition?

Comment: logn story short: it finally worked for me without strange syntax and unexplained errors - only explanation I can come up with is that I messed up something during the tests

Comment: Thanks to everyone who has tried to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I already written in comments above:
It finally worked for me without strange syntax and unexplained errors - only explanation I can come up with is that I messed up something during the tests.